Introducing series of document sections with a paragraph ending with a colon
In a technical document that introduces one into a complex device functioning, I have to provide a list of items with detailed description of each of them, with figures, tables and further (bulleted) lists, or even subsections.
I am tempted to use this pattern:

Sect. 42: Device components
[device diagram]
The device consists of the following parts:
42.1. Frobnicator
A frobnicator is a component that performs frobnication.
[image of the frobnicator]
Fronbication is required when the user is one of these species:

protogen
frobby-dobbler
wiggly-frobber

42.2. Wiggler
Wiggling is necessary for automating wiggling of the frobnicator.
Table 42.2.1: Wiggling rates



Component
Rate




frobnicator
1234 wiggles per second


widgeter
42 wiggles per second




This question is about the paragraph just above the section 42.1. It ends with a colon, but instead of introducing a bulleted list, it introduces several headings.
I've already seen the pattern somewhere, but I do not like it. Is it better to replace the colon with a period?
As an alternative, a bulleted list containing only names of the components could be placed before the detailed descriptions. But since this is a living document, it would be nice to avoid having another part that requires consistency with the rest of the document. I want to avoid this duplication at all costs, as the reader can use a table of contents.

This is more about language-independent interactive (navigable) computer display layouts than the English language. As such, it should probably be addressed on Stack Exchange User Experience

As I edit such docs, I'd always use: "The device consists of the parts that follow."

No, it is good the way it is.

You certainly could use a period. Whether you prefer a colon is really up to you, unless you're working to a very specific style guide. Unless someone can find a reference to such a style guide, it's probably a matter of opinion.
